# How to make Compose render my custom Shape?

Tags: kotlin, compose-desktop

I have this Composable that draws some text with a custom Shape behind it:

```
@Composable
fun TextWithIcon(text: String, icon: Shape) {
    Box(Modifier.size(48.dp)
        .border(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.secondaryVariant)
        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
        .padding(4.dp)
        .border(2.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.secondaryVariant, icon)
        .padding(4.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Text(text, color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground)
    }
}
```

Whenever I call it, Compose throws an Exception internally that doesn't even mention my code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to Image::makeFromBitmap Bitmap(_ptr=0x249bafa64c0)
    at org.jetbrains.skia.Image$Companion.makeFromBitmap(Image.kt:115)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SkiaBackedCanvas.drawImageRect-cI72Soc(SkiaBackedCanvas.skiko.kt:210)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SkiaBackedCanvas.drawImageRect-HPBpro0(SkiaBackedCanvas.skiko.kt:185)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.CanvasDrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs(CanvasDrawScope.kt:263)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs$default(DrawScope.kt:510)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.BorderKt$drawGenericBorder$3.invoke(Border.kt:318)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.BorderKt$drawGenericBorder$3.invoke(Border.kt:315)
    at androidx.compose.ui.draw.DrawContentCacheModifier.draw(DrawModifier.kt:218)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DrawEntity.draw(DrawEntity.kt:98)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.drawContainedDrawModifiers(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:320)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:310)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui(LayoutNode.kt:839)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.performDraw(InnerPlaceable.kt:90)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.drawContainedDrawModifiers(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:318)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:310)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.performDraw(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:139)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawContent(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:48)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.Background.draw(Background.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DrawEntity.draw(DrawEntity.kt:98)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.drawContainedDrawModifiers(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:320)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:310)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui(LayoutNode.kt:839)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.performDraw(InnerPlaceable.kt:90)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.drawContainedDrawModifiers(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:318)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:310)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui(LayoutNode.kt:839)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.performDraw(InnerPlaceable.kt:90)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.drawContainedDrawModifiers(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:318)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:60)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:340)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:339)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2117)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:113)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:339)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invokeOnCanvasInstance$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:161)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invokeOnCanvasInstance$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:161)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.SkiaLayer.performDrawLayer(SkiaLayer.skiko.kt:264)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.SkiaLayer.drawLayer(SkiaLayer.skiko.kt:225)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:305)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui(LayoutNode.kt:839)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.performDraw(InnerPlaceable.kt:90)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.drawContainedDrawModifiers(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:318)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:310)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui(LayoutNode.kt:839)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.SkiaBasedOwner.draw(SkiaBasedOwner.skiko.kt:347)
    at androidx.compose.ui.ComposeScene.render(ComposeScene.skiko.kt:419)
    at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer$1$onRender$1.invoke(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:316)
    at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer$1$onRender$1.invoke(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:315)
    at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer.catchExceptions(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer.access$catchExceptions(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:85)
    at androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer$1.onRender(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:315)
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.SkiaLayer.update$skiko(SkiaLayer.awt.kt:510)
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.redrawer.AWTRedrawer.update(AWTRedrawer.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.redrawer.Direct3DRedrawer$frameDispatcher$1.invokeSuspend(Direct3DRedrawer.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.redrawer.Direct3DRedrawer$frameDispatcher$1.invoke(Direct3DRedrawer.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.redrawer.Direct3DRedrawer$frameDispatcher$1.invoke(Direct3DRedrawer.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.FrameDispatcher$job$1.invokeSuspend(FrameDispatcher.kt:33)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@119c1b04, SwingDispatcher@56da22a8]
```

This happens for every shape, even one that doesn't even draw anything:

```
TextWithIcon("Hi", GenericShape { _, _ -> })
```

The weird thing is, I'm certain I've seen this code work and draw the shape. I'm just not sure what I changed between then and now, that broke it.

Removing everything from the `Modifier` except the (second) border doesn't help, still crashes. Also removing the `Box` content then fixes the crash, presumably because Compose knows the element is empty and won't even try to render it...

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Your code is working fine with `androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics:1.3.3`

Comment: I'm currently using Compose Desktop 1.2.0. I saw 1.3 was releasing soonish, I'll check that out.

Comment: @pushpull I upgraded to Compose Desktop 1.3.0, same error.

Comment: I tried it on compose desktop and it's running fine on 1.3.0. https://snipboard.io/CI4uqB.jpg

Comment: what is your java version?

Comment: @Dilshad Kotlin 1.7, Java 11

Comment: @Jorn seems like the composable function  you showed above is not related to the error.
check where the parameter `icon` is passed also code where method from `org.jetbrains.skia.Image$Companion` is used

Comment: @Jorn check if you getting same error after using  simple shapes(rectangle or circle) for parameter `icon`

Comment: @Dilshad One if my shapes is indeed a smiple square. Also, like the question says, one of them is *empty* and doesn't draw anything. And yes, it's related. If I comment out the line that draws the shape, the problem goes away. That information is *also* in the question.

Comment: @Jorn how can you draw empty because when you try to do that it invoke error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0`
means `GenericShape { _, _ -> }` is not supported

Comment: Looks like the empty shape was indeed the problem. It would have been really useful if that exception message had actually shown up, though.

Comment: @Jorn good to know you got it fixed. i will post this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Compose a shape is not allowed to be null or zero or empty. When you try to draw empty it usually invoke error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0` means `GenericShape { _, _ -> }` is not supported

but in your case the error is Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" which usually invoked on bad Initialization, this thread is for handling user events like clicks

you should change GenericShape to something which occupy width and height